# Angular material's dialog box not working correctly with hasBackdrop property or any other property that I assign

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog

I am trying to incorporate a dialog box with my application, but any properties I assign, such as hasBackdrop = true (I know this is the default value), is not changing the behavior.  When the dialog is open I am able to click anywhere in the UI and interact with it, all while the dialog remains open. Therefore, I am able to make API calls and even open multiple dialog boxes.

Here are some snippets of my ts file and html file.

```
export class MenuItemsComponent{

    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog){}

    @Input() menuItemsPerCategory: MenuItemModel[] = [];

    openDialog():void{
        const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
        dialogConfig.hasBackdrop = true;
        
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MenuItemDialogContainer, dialogConfig);
    }

<div (click)="openDialog()">
    {{ menuItemsPerCategory[0].name }}
</div>
}
```

Also, in the app module file I tried assigning this object under the providers array with no noted change.

```
   { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {hasBackdrop: false} }
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "example-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "16.1.6",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "16.1.6",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "16.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.3"
  }
}
```

I even went to material's official documentation page (https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples), clicked an one of the StackBlitz's example and did essentially a straight copy and paste job in visual studio code.  Unfortunately, my functionality is not mimicking what I am seeing on StackBlitz.  What I am seeing with my copy and paste job is the dialog remaining open when I click out of it and me being able to open multiple dialog boxes.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<button mat-button (click)="openDialog()">Launch dialog</button>`,
  //styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(DialogElementsExampleDialog);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-elements-example-dialog',
  template: `<h1 mat-dialog-title>Dialog with elements</h1>
             <div mat-dialog-content>This dialog showcases the title, close, content and actions elements.</div>
             <div mat-dialog-actions>
             <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
             </div>
            `
})
export class DialogElementsExampleDialog {}
```

Comment: Check in a navigator the .css of the Backdrop. It's looks like you have a display:none or or a wrong z-index in any place